# Switching maps in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm currently working on a 2D Top-Down RPG project with a couple others. At this point I've just implemented the ability to switch maps upon collision with the map bounds(up, down, left, right). However, I'm fairly sure that currently, when you switch maps, it's just keeping the old one in the memory which I think could probably cause memory issues down the line as the world gets bigger.

```
  public int setMap(int map)
{
  currentMap = map;
  tiledMap = MyGdxGame.getAssetManager().get(Integer.toString(currentMap) + ".tmx");
  tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
  return currentMap;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is ensure that the previous map isn't still there in the memory after switching to the new one. I thought that using the dispose() method for the previous map would be the solution, but it was throwing overflow errors. Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Show your code, how you're trying to dispose map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.dispose`on the tiledmap. This disposes of all the resources that this map uses. The other stuff will get collected by the GC eventually. Try the below example.

```
  public int setMap(int map)
{
  currentMap.dispose(); // Dispose your map first
  currentMap = map;
  tiledMap = MyGdxGame.getAssetManager().get(Integer.toString(currentMap) + ".tmx");
  tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
  return currentMap;
}
```

I never really used tiledmap object in LibGDX since I rather roll my own, so this might not work as intended. Take note of the following:

- You might need to initialize a new map after you disposed the previous.
- You are disposing resource assets here. Assets should be loaded again when you load another map, but this is a bit inefficient if they use the same assets. reuse them if possible.
- In case the player wants to move back into the previous map you might want to have a map buffer and dispose of them at a later stage. When you are building a buffer you could also try loading the neighboring maps asynchronously to eliminate load time of maps completely.